# как изменить массив с функции jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть такой код:

```
var qwqw = [];

var path = '/products/'+ productId +'.json';

jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: path,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
     dat(data);
  }
});

function dat (data) {
  jQuery.each (data.products, function(i, item){
    var asas = item.images[i].url;
    qwqw.push(asas);
   });
   console.log(qwqw);//выводит нужный массив
};

console.log(qwqw);//выводит пустой массив
```

Как глобально изменить массив `qwqw`?

Comment: а где вызов функции `dat`?

Comment: извиниет, поправил